# First order discount for guest customers checking Woocommerce orders billing email

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

By checking the GUEST customer's email address against processing and completed orders, I want to give the GUEST a "first order discount" if the email has no orders. It would be nice if this could happen as the guest types in their email.

I think I've managed to make the discount code and now I am asking for help on merging these two codes, making it all work.

Here's the discount code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'first_time_order_discount', 10, 1 );
function first_time_order_discount( $wc_cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') ) return;

    // discount percentage, change this into whatever you like
    // currently set to 5%
    $percent = 5;

    // calculate first order discount based on the percentage above
    $first_order_discount = $wc_cart->cart_contents_total * $percent / 100;
    $wc_cart->add_fee( __( 'First Order Discount', 'woocommerce')." ($percent%)", -$first_order_discount );
}
```

And here's the control code:

```
function has_bought( $customer_email ){
    $orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'post_status' => array('wc-processing', 'wc-completed'),
    ) );

    $email_array = array();

    foreach($orders as $order) {
        $order_obj = wc_get_order($order->ID);
        $order_obj_data = $order_obj->get_data();
        array_push($email_array, $order_obj_data['billing']['email']); 
    }
    if (in_array($customer_email, $email_array)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Not sure how to merge these two into one.

Comment: @helgatheviking you would not be able to help with this?

Comment: Just for info: Re-enable deleted answer and updated… check it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check customer *(guest or not)* orders from "Billing email" user live input requires Javascript and Ajax to enable (apply) a cart discount *(a negative fee)* on checkout page.

The complete code:

```
// Conditionally apply a percentage discount if customer has already make a purchase
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'first_time_purchase_percentage_discount', 10, 1 );
function first_time_purchase_percentage_discount( $cart ) {
    $percent = 5; // HERE set the discount percentage (float)

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') )
        return;

    if ( WC()->session->get( 'first_purchase_discount' ) && is_checkout() ) {
        // The First order discount percentage calulation
        $first_order_discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percent / 100;

        // Apply the discount
        $cart->add_fee( __( 'First Order Discount', 'woocommerce')." ($percent%)", -$first_order_discount );
    }
}

// The Wordpress Ajax PHP receiver
add_action( 'wp_ajax_checkout_billing_email', 'get_ajax_checkout_billing_email' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_checkout_billing_email', 'get_ajax_checkout_billing_email' );
function get_ajax_checkout_billing_email() {
    // Checking that the posted email is valid
    if ( isset($_POST['cb_email']) && filter_var($_POST['cb_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
        // Get one of customer orders from billing email
        $orders = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => 1, // Just one is enough
            'meta_key'    => '_billing_email',
            'meta_value'  => sanitize_email( $_POST['cb_email'] ),
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
            'post_status' => array('wc-processing', 'wc-completed')
        ) );

        // If the inputed billing email is not set on a customer order we set the value to TRUE
        $value = sizeof($orders) == 0 && ! empty($_POST['cb_email']) ? true : false;

        // Set the value in custom Woocommerce session identifier
        WC()->session->set('first_purchase_discount', $value );

        // Return the session value to jQuery
        echo WC()->session->get('first_purchase_discount');
    }
    die();
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'checkout_billing_email_js_ajax' );
function checkout_billing_email_js_ajax() {
    // Only on Checkout
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :

    // Initializing
    WC()->session->set('first_purchase_discount', false);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        if (typeof wc_checkout_params === 'undefined') 
            return false;

        $( 'input#billing_email' ).on('change blur', function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            console.log(value);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'checkout_billing_email',
                    'cb_email': value,
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    if( result == 1 ) {
                        // Update checkout
                        $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
                    }
                    console.log(result); // For testing (to be removed)
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**Addition:**

To handle "on hold" status too, replace the following line:

```
'post_status' => array('wc-processing', 'wc-completed')
```

by this:

```
'post_status' => array('wc-on-hold', 'wc-processing', 'wc-completed')
```

Comment: thank you, very kind of you to help. I'm not sure if this falls under the "new question" rule, but is it possible to add a text above the email field informing the user that the discount has been applied?

It's easy to "miss" otherwise. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: of course, I've upvoted and accepted. Again, thank you. Here's the new question. Kindly have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55409078/first-order-discount-add-on-hold-status-and-text-confirmation-above-email-field